# ASP.net MVC CheckBoxFor casting error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkboxfor

I have a EF entity that is tied to a SQL table that contains a bit field called "Active".  I generate the Edit code from the T4 template, and the page inherits from the EF entity.  At the bottom of the page, it generated a CheckBoxFor like this:

```
<%= Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Active) %>
```

I get the wonderful red squiggly under model.Active, and the error message says that I cannot implicitly convert type bool? to bool.  So, I tried the following:

```
<%= Html.CheckBoxFor(model => (bool)model.Active) %>
```

It, of course, didn't like that and gave me this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Templates can be used only with field
>   access, property access,
>   single-dimension array index, or
>   single-parameter custom indexer
>   expressions.

I'm probably missing something simple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490790/why-is-checkboxfor-producing-runtime-error

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try `model.Active.Value`

If this field should be not nullable then you should change data type on database side to `not null`.

**EDIT**

Why does this happen?

Your database field is defined as `FIELDNAME BIT NULL`. It means that it can contain three values: NULL, true and false. Since it can contain three values, it is mapped to bool? type in entity framework. bool? is another name of `Nullable<bool>`, which is wrapper around bool allowing it to have third value: NULL. Since CheckBoxFor expects one of two values - true or false, it can't except `Nullable<bool>`. Every Nullable has property called value which returns wrapped type. But you should be aware that when database field will contain null `Nullable<bool>.Value` will throw an error. If you are sure that this field should not contain NULL values, you should change it's data type to `FIELDNAME BIT NOT NULL` and generate model from database again. This will change data type from bool? to bool and there willbe no need to call Value property.

Comment: Bingo! Do you care to attempt an explanation of why this overcomes the type difference?

Comment: You rock, LukLed! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I just came across this question after having the same problem, and this answer solved mine. Thanks +1