# Why is CheckBoxFor producing runtime error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

The field the CheckBox is wired to is nullable.

On my view I get the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?'
>   to 'bool'

```
<%= Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Product.Exclusive) %>
```

How do I fix it without having to change the database design?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Exclusive cannot be Nullable, it makes no sense to the ViewEngine when evaluating the expression.  It has to either check or not check the checkbox and also respond with a `true` or `false` value.  Your model needs to have a `bool` value but that doesn't mean your database has to know that.  You just have to do a translation somewhere between the database and the Model, eg. `Model.Exclusive = DAO.Exclusive ?? false`.

Without knowing what null represents in your data schema or how you generate your model objects, it's hard to give you a lot more detail than that.

Edit: haven't tested this but you might get away with something as simple as

```
public bool NoNullExclusive
{
    get { return Exclusive ?? false; }
    set { Exclusive = value; }
}
```

and replacing

```
<%= Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Product.Exclusive) %>
```

with

```
<%= Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Product.NoNullExclusive) %>
```

Comment: I created the property you suggested in a partial class. Would this the best place to make this manipulation?

Comment: If your Product class is auto-generated then yes.  If not then either in the class itself or in the mapping from data access object to model.