# Bind CheckBoxFor to bool?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0

How to bind nullable bool to checkbox in MVC 2. I try with  this code in view:

```
<%: Html.CheckBoxFor(model =>  model.Communication.Before)%>
```

But show me compilation error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert bool? to bool

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is CheckBoxFor producing runtime error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490790/why-is-checkboxfor-producing-runtime-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know about this issue. You  can try to use this workaround:

Create new property  called Before in yours ViewModel:

```
public class YoursViewModel 
{
    public Communication Communication { get; set; }

    public bool Before
    {
        get
        {
            bool result;
            if (this.Communication.Before.HasValue)
            {
                result = (bool)this.Communication.Before.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                result = false;
            }

            return result;
        }
        set
        {
            this.Communication.Before = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Also you  have to  be careful for Communication property this have to be instanced before use. For example when you  initialize ViewModel in controller you  also have to  initialize this property.

```
ControllerAction()
{
  YoursViewModel model = ViewModelFactory.CreateViewModel<YoursViewModel >("");
  model.Communication = new Communication ();
  return View(model);
}
```

Thanks 
Ivan Baev

Comment: Note that you can simplify the `Before` getter to a single line: `return this.Communication.Before.GetValueOrDefault();`

Answer (score 2):

A checkbox can have two states: ckecked/uncheked, true/false, 1/0. So trying to bind a checkbox to a property that could potentially have three states doesn't really fit the picture. I would recommend you adapting your view model so that it uses a non nullable boolean property. If in your domain model you have a nullable boolean which you cannot change you could do this in the mapping layer between your domain model and view model.

Answer (score 1):

One way to bind Checkbox in MVC View

With EF database first, boolean (bit) field in the database produces a nullable bool? Property in the generated class. For demo I have a table named Dude with the fields

- Id uniqueidentifier
- Name varchar(50)
- IsAwesome bit

The following class is generated by EF:

```
namespace NullableEfDemo
{
 using System;
 public partial class Dude
 {
    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsAwesome { get; set; }
 }
}
```

To be able to bind IsAwesome to checkbox I simply extend the class Dude. This is to avoid editing the generated class, if I need to refresh it.  So I added a code file *DudePartial.cs* to my project (the name is irrelevant). Don’t forget to declare or using the project namespace:

```
namespace NullableEfDemo
{
 partial class Dude
 {
    public bool Awesome
    {
        get { return IsAwesome ?? false; }
        set { IsAwesome = value; }
    }
  }
}
```

This declares a new property **Awesome** of type bool that can be bound to the checkbox in the Edit view

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Awesome, new { @class = "control-label" })
```

In the HttpPost I’m binding the models Awesome property instead of IsAwesome.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Awesome")] Dude dude)
    {…
```

Answer (score 0):

Untick the Bit column in the database that allows NULLs and add a default value e.g. 0
Then change any exist cells from Null to 0 or 1 (false or true)
This allows you to work with the 'value'

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35701412)

Comment: This question got an accepted answer in 2011!